# Contact page. Which is the better wording?

Tags: website-design, terminology, copywriting, wording, contact-us

What is the most appropriate Contact page title for a website?
Contact, Contacts, Contact us or other?

1. Contacts is used, among others, in iOS and Android.
   Seems to me more related to a list of personal contacts on a device, e-mail account etc.
2. Contact us (or Contact Us) is used in many big websites (Microsoft, SAP, Oracle, ...)
3. Contact doesn't sound right to me (verb or noun?)

**UPDATE**: all very valid answers, thanks a lot for the suggestiosns

Comment: Is this website for a company? small firm? 1 person?

Comment: for a small company

Comment: Also `reach to us`, `ask us` etc... if you don't wont to reveal your location, or you have more than one location or any other reasons. We at our team blog use `Reach us` type text where we show our list of social networks and mail ids, coz in such cases a single address is not feasible. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by no means definitive, but it is where I would use them and why:

- **Contact** refers to a **single person**, so it is something that I would suggest on a blog or personal site.
- **Contacts** refers to a **list of contacts** (usually in an address book), so I would avoid it on a website unless referring to a list of contacts rather than the action contact.
- **Contact us** is my preferred wording for a website as it implies that you will contact the **organisation** behind the website.  It is the most common on commercial websites and also what, in my experience, most people look for.  It is also a **call to action**, which has a positive encouragement to contact the website.

Answer (score 3):

Contacts is used in context of the **user's own personal connections** stored in his phonebook, social network, etc.

Contact us is used in context of an entity/organization giving a medium via which a visitor/user can **get in touch with** them.

Comment: Yes, and "Contact" without the "us" is unclear. Unless it's in Dutch, then it's quite common to just use "contact".

Answer (score 2):

Contact Us is more prominently used however there are no set guidelines as to what you can't use. However I would stay away from Contacts unless there are more than one.

In my agency we use Contact Us because it's representing a large company. Many other websites that represent large firms use Contacts Us such as: [Samsung](https://www.samsung.com/us/) and [Apple](http://www.apple.com/).

Contact Us is a more common pattern convention used on many websites however, you can look at [Pattern Tap](http://patterntap.com/tags/type/contact) that displays many website patterns using Contact Us among various other resources for example: "Get in Touch" and "Connect with Us". There is no set guideline saying you cant use Contact but using Pattern Tap may guide you in the right direction as to what wording would be more beneficial for you to convey your message.